# DropDownList Cascata e Composta MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho uma seguinte duvida

Tenho 1 classe Usuário e composta por outras classes Gênero,Curso e Semestre

Ex

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public Genero Sexo { get; set; } = new Genero();
    public Curso Curso { get; set; } = new Curso();
    public Semestre Semestre { get; set; } = new Semestre();
```

E minha duvida e na minha controller para popular minhas DropDownListFor

Minhas classes DAO Iguais a de Curso e Semestre

```
    public List<Genero> ListarGenero()
    {
        var Genero = new List<Genero>();
        SqlDataReader reader;

        using (contexto = new Contexto())
        {
            var strQuery = " SELECT * FROM Genero ";
            reader = contexto.ExecutaComandoComRetorno(strQuery);

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var temObjeto = new Genero()
                {
                    id = int.Parse(reader["Id"].ToString()),
                    Sexo = reader["Genero"].ToString()
                };
                Genero.Add(temObjeto);
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
        return Genero;
    }
```

Minha Action

```
    public ActionResult GetGenero()
    {
        GeneroDAO gen = new GeneroDAO();
        ViewBag.Genero = new SelectList(gen.ListGenero(), "Id", "Sexo");
        return View();
    }
```

View

```
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Sexo.id, (SelectList)ViewBag.Genero, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Procurei em alguns foruns nao achei nada usando composição
Gostaria de como fazer para popular as dropdown vindo do banco e tambem fazer em cascata no curso, so achei com JavaScript porem nao posso utilizar pq ele tambem nao reconhece a composição das outras classes

[image: Ele apresenta esse erro]

Comment: Não seria apenas
`@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Sexo  ...`

Answer (score -1):

Manda na viewbag a lista de generos e na view coloca

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Sexo.id, new SelectList
(
  ViewBag.Genero, "Id", "Sexo"
),"Insira o sexo", new { @class = "form-control" })
```